# Is there a way to stop a python file from closing?

Tags: python

Im making a game that is based just on typing, kind of like a textRPG (keep in mind ive just started to learn python)
pretty much its just

GoOutside = "You go outside, would you like to go to the town or into the forest?/ Town - Go into the town/ Forest - Go into the forest

When i compile this into an actual program it closes immediately, is there a way to make it not close?

Comment: If you need to get the user's input use the function input() and that will make the program wait for the user's input

Comment: What does "compile this into an actual program" mean? A python script does not need compiling.

Comment: first run code manually in console/terminal and you will have open console after ending code. Maybe you get some error message. And if user has to put some text then you need ie. `result = input("Select direction: ")` to get it. BTW: if you write number `123` then it gives string `"123"` and you have to convert it `int(result)` if you need number.